# Relation between a basis for the row space and a basis for the column space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $A \in R^{m \times n}$ let $\{v_1 , v_2, \cdots , v_r \}$ be a basis for the row space of $A$. How would you prove that the set $\{Av_1 , Av_2, \cdots , Av_r \}$ forms a basis for the column space of $A$ ?

Comment: Note that the notation implies that $A$ isn't the null matrix. Clearly $Av_1,\ldots ,Av_r$ is a set of vectors in the column space and since the dimension of the column space is determined by the rank of $A$ (which is $r$), the only thing left to prove is that $\{Av_1,\ldots ,Av_r\}$ is a linearly independent set. Suppose it isn't. Then there are scalars $\alpha _1, \ldots ,\alpha _r$ such that $\sum \limits_{n=1}^rAv_n=0_{m\times 1}$ and at least one of the $\alpha$'s isn't $0$. Now a minimaly argument for $n$ should do the trick, but this margin is too short to contain the proof.

Comment: You mean $\sum_{i = 1}^r \alpha_i Av_i = 0_{m \times 1} $ right? If we assume $ A \neq $ null-matrix then: $ A \sum_{i = 1}^r \alpha_i v_i = 0_{m \times 1} $ and I think this way it's proven that the vectors are linearly independet

Comment: Yes, I meant that.